# In R Shiny, how to allow a change in reactive user inputs to retain through the next click of an action button that permits modification?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

In the first MWE code below, it works perfectly - user clicks on "Modify" action button, in the modal dialogue that pops up the user makes a change to the matrix user input grid, user dismisses the modal dialog, clicks on "Modify" again, and those user inputs are retained (or "stick around") in the matrix input grid (and output table) without any sort of reset back to default. Perfect, works as intended.

In the second MWE code below, inside the "Liabilities module" tab, user inputs do not retain from one click of "Modify..." action button (rendered in the sidebar panel) to the next. Each click of "Modify..." resets the user input grid back to default values.

I've been trying to copy the reactivity chain from the first MWE to the 2nd MWE, without luck. My understanding of reactivity isn´t deep enough. Could someone please help me through this, and explain what needs to be done and why if possible?

First MWE code where user inputs correctly retain:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)

# Function assigns row headers to input matrix grid
  matrix3Headers <- function(){
    c('A','B','C','D')}

# Assigns default values to first column of input matrix grid
  matrix3Default <- matrix(c(1,24,0,100),4,1,dimnames=list(matrix3Headers(),NULL))

# Automatically assigns names to column headers
  colnames(matrix3Default) <- paste0("Series ",1:ncol(matrix3Default))

# Matrix input function
  matrix3Input <- function(x, matrix3Default){
  matrixInput(x, 
              label =  'Input series terms into below grid, formatted version shown at bottom:',
              value =  matrix3Default, 
              rows  =  list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE), 
              cols  =  list(extend=TRUE,names=TRUE,editableNames=FALSE,delete=TRUE),
              class =  'numeric'
    ) # close matrix input
  } # close function

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  titlePanel('Liabilities Inputs'),
  fluidRow(actionButton('show','Show'),
           actionButton('modify','Modify'),
           actionButton('hide','Hide'),
           actionButton('reset','Reset'),
           tableOutput('table2')
  ) # close fluid row
) # close fluid page

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(
        mat3=matrix3Input('matrix3',matrix3Default),
        input=matrix3Default,
        colHeader = colnames(input)
        ) # close reactive values
  
  hide('table2')
  
  observeEvent(input$modify,{
    showModal(modalDialog(
      rv$mat3,
      tableOutput('table1')
    )) # close shown modal and modal dialog
    hide('table2')
  }) # close observe event
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({
    rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3',input$matrix3)
      
      # Indented section below assigns sequential column headers to output tables:
        df <- input$matrix3
        n <- dim(df)[2]
        
      # Below indented code adds numeric formats to table output  
        dfA <- format(df[1,],nsmall=0)
        dfB <- format(df[2,],nsmall=0)
        dfC <- paste(format(df[3,],nsmall=2),'%')
        dfD <- paste(format(df[4,],nsmall=2),'%')
        df <- rbind(df[0,],dfA,dfB,dfC,dfD)
        rownames(df) <- matrix3Headers()
    rv$input <- df
    colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
    df
    },rownames=TRUE, colnames=TRUE)
  
  observeEvent(input$show,show('table2'))
  
  observeEvent(input$hide, hide('table2'))
  
  observeEvent(input$reset,{
    hide('table2')
    rv$input <- matrix3Default
    rv$mat3 <- matrix3Input('matrix3', matrix3Default)
    }) # close observe event
  
  output$table2 <- renderTable({
    df <- rv$input
    n <- dim(df)[2]
    colnames(df) <- paste("Series", 1:n)
    df
    },rownames=TRUE)
  
} # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Second MWE code that needs to have user inputs "stick around":

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

button2 <- function(x,y){actionButton(x,y,style="width:90px;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:80%")}

matrix1Input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE),
              cols = list(extend=FALSE,names=FALSE,editableNames=FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

pct <- function(x){paste(format(round(x*100,digits=1),nsmall=1),"%",sep="")} # convert to percentage

vectorBase <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x)
  b <- seq(1:x)
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
  return(c)}

vectorPlot <- function(w,x,y,z){
  plot(w[,1],sapply(w[,2], function(x)gsub("%","",x)), # << per YBS solution Aug 27, 2021
       main=x,
       xlab=y,
       ylab=z,
       type="b",
       col="blue",
       pch=19,cex=1.25
       ) # close plot
  } # close function

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model..."),
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")),align="center",
                        style="margin-top:-15px;margin-bottom:5px")),
      # Panels rendered with uiOuput & renderUI in server to stop flashing at invocation
      uiOutput("Panels") 
    ), # close sidebar panel
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("By balances", value=2),
        tabPanel("By accounts", value=3), 
        tabPanel("Liabilities module", value=4,
                 fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                 fluidRow(
                   button2('showRatesValueBtn','Rates values'),
                   button2('showRatesPlotBtn','Rates plots'),
                 ), # close fluid row
                 
                 div(style = "margin-top: 5px"),
                 
                 # Shows outputs on each page of main panel   
                 uiOutput('showResults')), 
        id = "tabselected"
      ) # close tabset panel
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  
  base_input  <- reactive(input$base_input)
  showResults <- reactiveValues()
  
  yield   <- function(){vectorBase(60,input$base_input[1,1])} # Must remain in server section
  
  # --- Conditional panels rendered here rather than in UI to eliminate invocation flashing ------------>
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==4",
        actionButton('modRates','Modify Rates and Coupons',
                     style='width:100%;background-color:LightGrey'
                     ),
        setShadow(id='modRates'),
        div(style = "margin-bottom: 10px"),
      ), # close conditional panel
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==3"),
      conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==4")
    ) # close tagList
  }) # close renderUI
  
  # --- Below defines the vectorsAll object before user clicks on actionButton "Input Liabilities" ---->
  vectorsAll <- reactive({
    if (is.null(input$modRates)){df <- NULL}
    else {
      if(input$modRates < 1){df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,BaseRate = pct(0.2))}  # define what you want to display by default
      else {
        req(input$base_input)
        df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,BaseRate = pct(yield()[,2]))
      } # close 2nd else
    } # close 1st else
    df
  }) # close reactive
  
  output$table1 <- renderTable({vectorsAll()})
  
  # --- Below produces vector values after clicking "Vector Values" button; see above for pre-click ---->
  observeEvent(input$showRatesValueBtn,
               {showResults$showme <-
                 tagList(tableOutput("table1"))
               },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  
  # --- Below produces vector plots -------------------------------------------------------------------->   
  output$graph1 <-renderPlot(vectorPlot(vectorsAll(),"A Variable","Period","Rate"))
  observeEvent(input$showRatesPlotBtn,{showResults$showme <- plotOutput("graph1")})
  
  # --- Below sends both vector plots and vector values to UI section above ---------------------------->
  output$showResults <- renderUI({showResults$showme})
  
  # --- Below for modal dialog inputs ------------------------------------------------------------------>
  observeEvent(input$modRates,
               {showModal(modalDialog(
                 matrix1Input("base_input"),
                 div(style = "margin-top: 0px"),
                 useShinyjs(),
               ) # close modalDialog
               ) # close showModal
               } # close showModal function
  ) # close observeEvent
  
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `modalDialog` reset the table every time you click the button. and `matrix1Input` always uses the default value. You need to do it as your first example. When the table is rendered, you no longer re-render it with default values but to use old values.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

button2 <- function(x,y){actionButton(x,y,style="width:90px;margin-bottom:5px;font-size:80%")}

mDefaults <- matrix(c(0.2), 4, 1,dimnames=list(c("A","B","C","D"),NULL))
matrix1Input <- function(x, defaults){
    matrixInput(x, 
                value = defaults,
                rows = list(extend=FALSE,names=TRUE),
                cols = list(extend=FALSE,names=FALSE,editableNames=FALSE),
                class = "numeric")}

pct <- function(x){paste(format(round(x*100,digits=1),nsmall=1),"%",sep="")} # convert to percentage

vectorBase <- function(x,y){
    a <- rep(y,x)
    b <- seq(1:x)
    c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a)
    return(c)}

vectorPlot <- function(w,x,y,z){
    plot(w[,1],sapply(w[,2], function(x)gsub("%","",x)), # << per YBS solution Aug 27, 2021
         main=x,
         xlab=y,
         ylab=z,
         type="b",
         col="blue",
         pch=19,cex=1.25
    ) # close plot
} # close function

ui <- 
    pageWithSidebar(
        headerPanel("Model..."),
        sidebarPanel(
            fluidRow(helpText(h5(strong("Base Input Panel")),align="center",
                              style="margin-top:-15px;margin-bottom:5px")),
            # Panels rendered with uiOuput & renderUI in server to stop flashing at invocation
            uiOutput("Panels") 
        ), # close sidebar panel
        mainPanel(
            tabsetPanel(
                tabPanel("By balances", value=2),
                tabPanel("By accounts", value=3), 
                tabPanel("Liabilities module", value=4,
                         fluidRow(h5(strong(helpText("Select model output to view:")))),
                         fluidRow(
                             button2('showRatesValueBtn','Rates values'),
                             button2('showRatesPlotBtn','Rates plots'),
                         ), # close fluid row
                         
                         div(style = "margin-top: 5px"),
                         
                         # Shows outputs on each page of main panel   
                         uiOutput('showResults')), 
                id = "tabselected"
            ) # close tabset panel
        ) # close main panel
    ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
    
    base_input  <- reactive(input$base_input)
    showResults <- reactiveValues()
    
    yield   <- function(){vectorBase(60,input$base_input[1,1])} # Must remain in server section
    
    # --- Conditional panels rendered here rather than in UI to eliminate invocation flashing ------------>
    output$Panels <- renderUI({
        tagList( 
            conditionalPanel(
                condition="input.tabselected==4",
                actionButton('modRates','Modify Rates and Coupons',
                             style='width:100%;background-color:LightGrey'
                ),
                setShadow(id='modRates'),
                div(style = "margin-bottom: 10px"),
            ), # close conditional panel
            conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==3"),
            conditionalPanel(condition="input.tabselected==4")
        ) # close tagList
    }) # close renderUI
    
    # --- Below defines the vectorsAll object before user clicks on actionButton "Input Liabilities" ---->
    vectorsAll <- reactive({
        if (is.null(input$modRates)){df <- NULL}
        else {
            if(input$modRates < 1){df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,BaseRate = pct(0.2))}  # define what you want to display by default
            else {
                req(input$base_input)
                df <- cbind(Period = 1:60,BaseRate = pct(yield()[,2]))
            } # close 2nd else
        } # close 1st else
        df
    }) # close reactive
    output$table1 <- renderTable({vectorsAll()})
    
    # --- Below produces vector values after clicking "Vector Values" button; see above for pre-click ---->
    observeEvent(input$showRatesValueBtn,
                 {showResults$showme <-
                     tagList(tableOutput("table1"))
                 },ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
    # --- Below produces vector plots -------------------------------------------------------------------->   
    output$graph1 <-renderPlot(vectorPlot(vectorsAll(),"A Variable","Period","Rate"))
    observeEvent(input$showRatesPlotBtn,{showResults$showme <- plotOutput("graph1")})
    
    # --- Below sends both vector plots and vector values to UI section above ---------------------------->
    output$showResults <- renderUI({showResults$showme})
    
    # --- Below for modal dialog inputs ------------------------------------------------------------------>
    observeEvent(input$modRates,
                 {showModal(modalDialog(
                     matrix1Input("base_input", if(is.null(input$base_input)) mDefaults else input$base_input),
                     div(style = "margin-top: 0px"),
                     useShinyjs(),
                 ) # close modalDialog
                 ) # close showModal
                 } # close showModal function
    ) # close observeEvent
    
}) # close server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I added the default argument. When your table exists, I use the existing value instead of the default value.

Comment: It's a simple fix, few changes. I summarize the changes so perhaps I remember when I encounter this need in the future: (1) separately define the default inputs as "mDefaults" (using "mat1DefaultValues" in my implementation), (2) expand matrix1Input function with value = "defaults" (in my implementation, using "matrix1Input" instead of "default" to minimize extra terms, works so far, hope this doesn't buggify later), (3) in observeEvent for modal dialog, add a conditional: in invoking matrix1Input function, if user hasn't input, use default values otherwise use the user input values.